# how do you call and update a variable with the new integer value of a specific string within an array after it has been shuffled?

Tags: arrays, swift

```
weak var numberwordimage: UIImageView!

var numberwords = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
var zero = 0

extension Array {
public mutating func shuffle() {
    for i in stride(from: count - 1, to: 1, by: -1) {
        let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(i+1)))
        if i != random {
            self.swapAt(i, random)}}}
}

numberwords.shuffle()
```

Lets say the shuffle function rearanged this array to be

```
["five", "four", two","one","zero","three"]
```

How do I update the variable of Zero to its new Array integer value of 4?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the question just get the *index* in the array for given element

```
zero = numberwords.index(of: "zero")!
```